# Need help in understanding what is going on in C program

Tags: c

So I have very weird bug that I cannot understand. I am running loop and checking for NULL value then I suppose to terminate loop. But, I am getting some EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue after I have the following values (as you can see on the screenshot)

This is additional piece of code that returns char string

```
char *TKGetNextToken(TokenizerT *tk) {

    if((*tk).currentToken)
        return *(*tk).currentToken++;
    else
        return NULL;

}
```

and actual structure

```
struct TokenizerT_ {
    char **currentToken;
    char **tokens;
}tokenizer;
```

And that is what I have for my pointers:

```
 char **words;
 words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords);
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
 words[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(ts)+1);

 tokenizer.tokens = words;
 tokenizer.currentToken = words;
```

I have no idea why this error can occur and why. Because we can have either pointer that points somewhere or NULL value... 
[image]

Comment: You should check `*(*tk).currentToken` too, before you increment it.

Comment: And you're not going out of bounds of `currentToken`? How do you create all those pointers?

Comment: "_I have no idea why this error can occur_ " - Typical when you have pointers pointing to no memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I added code with memory allocation

Answer (score 1):

Your TKGetNextToken tests for a NULL that is never present.  Add a NULL entry at the end:

```
words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (numberOfWords +1));
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
    words[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(ts)+1);
words[i] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I fixed my code thanks to Joachim and JosEdu.
 words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); needs numberOfWords + 1
Because when I am going out of bounds and checking for null value it just has some not allocated chunk of memory and I am running into trouble.